# Disable button once clicked Cheatengine Lua

Tags: lua, cheat-engine

So I've been struggling making a button that on pressed goes to a link and toggles Enabled to false so you cant click it anymore

```
function CEButton1Click(sender)
shellExecute("https://google.com/search")
CEButton1.Enabled=false
end
```

The above is what I have so far but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: What is not working? The click isn't working, the button remains enabled?

Comment: Yes the button remains enabled.

Comment: also setEnabled("false") doesent work.

Comment: So... You are expecting Cheat Engine - a program to operate on many other programs as generically as possible - to automatically know that the launched program is a web browser, find the checkbox in memory after the page has loaded, and be able to set it? And to expose it under the names that you've guessed?

Comment: Doesn't sound like thats what @Tero is trying to do. If you print the button status does it make sense? Not familiar with cheatengine but something like `print(CEButton.getEnabled)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for cheat engine is severely lacking, but sender in that function is actually the button itself. This means you can simple do

```
sender.Enabled = false
```

and that successfully disables the button.

[image: It works!]